# How to set smtp_password in GCP Cloud Composer for configuring third-party SMTP services

Tags: smtp, email-server, google-cloud-platform, composer, apache-airflow

I can use only G Suit SMTP mail server due to company security policy.

I want to configuring 3rd-party SMTP service for using G Suit mail service but I can't set "smtp smtp_password" config in AIRFLOW CONFIGURATION OVERRIDES tap of Cloud Composer.

GCP Guides says *"smtp  smtp_password   The default SMTP password for Airflow. You cannot configure a new password."*

[GCP Cloud Composer 3rd-party Email Setting guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS1F2.png)

Is there any method to set smtp_password in Cloud Composer config? Or any other method of setting G suite mail server for using email sending on DAG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the `smtp_password` value, as is shown on the page you took the screenshot from. You must use the default password given.

> Using a third-party SMTP service requires using the default, publicly known Airflow smtp_password. Cloud Composer does not support configuring the smtp_password because the value is stored in plain text in airflow.cfg and considered unsecure. Use this option only if the connection between the Airflow web server and the SMTP server is secure.

[image: Configuring third-party SMTP services]

For anyone who wants to look at the page the screengrab was taken from:

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_third-party_smtp_services